# Generating a new curve using an existing curve and new prime

Tags: elliptic-curves, diffie-hellman, prime-numbers, elliptic-curve-generation

Can you take a curve equation from https://safecurves.cr.yp.to and a large safe prime from existing DH parameters (for example `openssl dhparam 9000`), combine them, and result in a secure ECDH curve?
Are there some special considerations when pairing a curve equation with a prime?

The generator point would be SHAKE(something).

Comment: The primes that define the curves are usually chosen for fast arithmetic like  $2^{255}-19$. The generator point is not really important (other than nothing-in-my-sleeves)

Comment: The brainpool curves are exceptions to this kind of choice of prime, by the way.

Comment: so for ECC any random prime will be secure? doesn't even have to be a safe prime?

Comment: No, once you set up your curve, the new area starts... Will it satisfy the criterias?

Comment: Among many issues, we'd need to recompute the curve's order, requiring an implementation of [Schoof–Elkies–Atkin’s algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schoof%E2%80%93Elkies%E2%80%93Atkin_algorithm) or similar that works in acceptable time for fields with >10 times wider primes than commonly used. And use of the curve would be like 10000 times slower than Ed25519.